# If "I read the book in five minutes" is to duration, what is "I read the book five minutes ago?"

Tags: terminology, time, time-reference

If **duration** is the general term for the class of words that reference the time difference between now and the future when an event is finished (i.e. I read the book **in five minutes**), **what is the general term** for the class of words that reference the time difference between now and the past when an event occurred (i.e. I read the book **five minutes ago**?

**Context:**
I am looking for the hypernym to use as a descriptor that references **how long ago** an event occurred with respect to the current time.

Comment: Temporal remoteness?

Comment: Welcome to ELL.SE. As requests for help with naming are explicitly off-topic, I have edited your post to specify that you are seeking a term. As this question may not be of direct interest to English learners, you might try our sister site for advanced English users, [ELU.SE]; see the guidance for [single word requests](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info).

Comment: ***5 minutes ago*** (or ***5 minutes earlier, later, from now, before, after[wards]*** etc.) are just "special cases" of duration. Specifically, *duration **offset*** - "temporal distance" from a reference point in time (***now***, contextually-identified "narrative time", etc.). Linguists might call them "temporal locatives", I dunno. But "duration" is just the temporal version of "distance" in standard *spatial* contexts.

Comment: Who ever said that duration cannot be in the past? duration is a length of time, not a moment in time. Duration is not **the general term for the class of words that reference the time difference between now and the future**

Comment: I suggest this is more a question of Linguistics rather than English Language Learning. Perhaps you'd be better asking at linguistics.se

Comment: It's potentially interesting to contrast *I read that book in April last year* and *I read that book in an hour last week*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Age* might work, even though typically *age* is used in terms of days/months/weeks, or something not recent in relation to the context.

*Recentness* seems to be a word (or *recency*) that you can use if the times would typically be short.

*Time ago* is a short two word phrase that would work regardless of the length of time.

Comment: recency is not a word I would suggest to ELLers, myself.

Comment: wouldn't it be better to say:  "I was reading the book five minutes ago"? I read the book five minutes ago to me sounds like he read the whole book five minutes ago.

Comment: OP is looking for a single word.

Answer (score 1):

If *Age* is too generic, perhaps ***elapsed time*** would work.  It refers to the difference between any two points in time.  (In many cases it is used synonymously with *duration*, as the two points chosen are the start and end of an event.)

Answer (score 0):

The present time: how long ago an event occurred with respect to the present time.

- **past time of occurrence** [yesterday, two months ago. etc.]

duration is not about when something occurs. It's about how long it occurs.

Comment: On a hunch, I found a few dozen instances of ["temporal localizer"](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22temporal+localizer%22) in Google Books. Where ***now*** is apparently a typical example. And OP's specific context is one that does indeed depend on being associated with a specific "when" (the present moment), so it's not *entirely* just a matter of "How long?" As it would be in, say, ***a five-minute walk*** .

Comment: @FumbleFingers So enter it as an answer. The OP's question understands the term duration incorrectly. Five-minute walk is duration, of course.